# save data from datagridview in c #

Tags: c#, datagridview, save

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSC29.jpg) I get a problem in storing data.
before that I have the data that has been displayed in the DataGridview and I want to store data from the DataGridview in the form of * txt. I have tried to save the data but only one data is stored not all.

Here I show you my code. Hope someone can help me? Thanks a lot before

```
row.Cells["colProjection"].Value = string.Join("\t", feature.Select(f => Math.Abs(f / 30).ToString("N3")));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\OKE.txt");
            writer.Write(row.Cells["colProjection"].Value);
            writer.WriteLine("");
            writer.Close();
```

Comment: Why you wrote your whole expression into that cell (with tabulation), then tried to write to text file from that cell?  Just write your expression into text file.

Comment: You save one cell you have one cell. Obvious. If you have more Cells you need to write them all. If you want it in one text file add a row speparator, maybe '\v': If you have more rows the same applies. Maybe use `\r` to separate rows or, as you do now a newline sequence.

Comment: Because my datagridview format is like that. There is a column for displaying images and there is a column to display the value. And I will save the value in the column that displays that value. @SeM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get all rows data, you can use a `for` loop to do it , something like this:

```
  StringBuilder sr=new StringBuilder();
  for (int i=0 ;i>=mygrid.Rows.Count;i++)
  {
     sr.AppendLine(mygrid.Rows[i].Cells["colProjection"].Text);
  }

  System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\output.txt",sr.ToString());
```

**UPDATE :**

```
private void btnFeature_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pca == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please compute the analysis first!");
        return;
    }

    ImageToArray converter = new ImageToArray(min: 0, max: 1);

    int rows = dataGridView3.Rows.Count;
    double[][] inputs = new double[rows][];
    double[][] features = new double[rows][];
    int[] outputs = new int[rows];

    int index = 0;
    StringBuilder sr=new StringBuilder();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
    {
        Bitmap image = row.Cells["colFace2"].Value as Bitmap;
        int label = (int)row.Cells["colLabel2"].Value;

        double[] input;
        converter.Convert(image, out input);

        double[] feature = pca.Transform(input);

        row.Cells["colProjection"].Value = string.Join("\t", feature.Select(f => Math.Abs(f / 30).ToString("N3")));
       // TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\OKE.txt");
        /*for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.RowCount; i++)
        {
            writer.Write(); 
        }*/

        sr.Append(row.Cells["colProjection"].Text);// Or .Value


        row.Tag = feature;
        inputs[index] = input;
        features[index] = feature;
        outputs[index] = label;
        index++;
    }
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\OKE.txt",sr.ToString());
}
```

Comment: sorry, I tried your code. but, the program still doesn't work and the error is in the code "row [i]". I got an error
"cannot applay indexing with [] to an expression to type 'datagridview' ". So, what should I do?

Comment: its just a sample, use `mygrid.Rows[i].Cells["colProjection"].Value;` instead of `row[i].Cells["colProjection"].Value`

Comment: @IrmaDewita I have updated answer. Also please replace **.Value** with **.Text** in my previous comment.

Comment: yes I understand, I have succeeded in using the looping function to make the data stored entirely. But when I see data in txt, the value in the first row is the same as the second row and so on. what should I do to overcome the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I use to store data.
But the stored data still has errors. Because the stored data is the last row data instead of data from the first row to the last row.

```
private void btnFeature_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pca == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please compute the analysis first!");
            return;
        }

        ImageToArray converter = new ImageToArray(min: 0, max: 1);

        int rows = dataGridView3.Rows.Count;
        double[][] inputs = new double[rows][];
        double[][] features = new double[rows][];
        int[] outputs = new int[rows];

        int index = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
        {
            Bitmap image = row.Cells["colFace2"].Value as Bitmap;
            int label = (int)row.Cells["colLabel2"].Value;

            double[] input;
            converter.Convert(image, out input);

            double[] feature = pca.Transform(input);

            row.Cells["colProjection"].Value = string.Join("\t", feature.Select(f => Math.Abs(f / 30).ToString("N3")));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\OKE.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.RowCount; i++)
            {
                writer.Write(row.Cells["colProjection"].Value + "\t"); 
            }
            writer.WriteLine("");
            writer.Close();

            row.Tag = feature;
            inputs[index] = input;
            features[index] = feature;
            outputs[index] = label;
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `row.Cells["colProjection"].Value = string.Join("\t", feature.Select(f => Math.Abs(f / 30).ToString("N3")));`
What does this code line do?

Comment: Code used to display values in "colprojetion" on each row in the form of an array.

Comment: Excuse me, but need more clarification.
`row` What does this refer to? 
why you don't used current rows Index `i` to retrieve all rows in loop (As I explained in the previous answer)?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what that means. but I have updated the complete code that I use. I hope you can help me solve my problem. thank you @MKH

Comment: Hmm, You are trying to get all rows by `ForeEach` loop but why you are using a `for` loop inside it? this `for` loop repeat each row that retrieved from `foreach` for `.RowCount` times and then save it to file. Also please put your Save & Close Writer after `foreach` ends , because this is why you are saving just One record (last row in this case) for `n` times in output file.

Comment: can you give an example of what we said earlier using the code that I sent.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me save all data in datagridview to txt. the data has been stored all in txt. But I have a problem again. The stored data instead piles up into one long line. And I find it difficult to distinguish the first data from other data.

Comment: you're welcome , you can use line break at end of each row so just Replace `sr.Append(row.Cells["colProjection"].Text);` to `sr.AppendLine(row.Cells["colProjection"].Text);` for new lines. Also you can use **'\r\n'** instead of **'\t'**

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, it works properly. And you have helped me a lot in solving the problems I experienced :)

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that , If answer has solved your problem, then please mark it as answer so that others will use it too.

Comment: okay, I will mark it as an answer so that other people will use it too.